# SSH not passing LANG environment variable

Tags: bash, ssh, debian, environment-variables, sshd

I'm running a Debian server (`uname -v` output `#1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1 (2017-12-23)`). When I log in from any of several clients (macOS 10.13 laptop with default ssh, the "Prompt" app on iOS, among others), `LANG=C`, despite passing in `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` from the client. Here is some relevant information:

```
client$ env | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
client$ ssh -v server
...
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
server$ env | grep LANG
LANG=C
server$ grep -in lang /etc/profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile ~/.bash_logout ~/.bashrc
grep: ~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
grep: ~/.bash_login: No such file or directory
server$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_US.utf8
server$ sudo sshd -T | grep acceptenv
acceptenv LANG
acceptenv LC_*
```

So, `ssh` claims to be sending `LANG`, `sshd` claims to be accepting `LANG`, and `LANG` is not being set in any of the `bash` startup/shutdown files.

I know I could "fix" this with a setting in `~/.profile` or somesuch, but I'm more interested in why the environment isn't getting passed properly.

Edit:

I just noticed that the `LANG` name is different on macOS and Debian. This still doesn't work, however:

```
client$ LANG=en_US.utf8 ssh -v server
...
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8
server$ env | grep LANG
LANG=C
```

Edit 2:

This difference in names isn't, it turns out, a Mac-vs-Linux issue. `locale -a` reports a different name for the locale than is used by `$LANG`. I haven't bothered to investigate why.

Comment: Maybe it is overriden by some profile processing dring the logon on the server? Same problem here between two Ubuntus... LANG seems clobbered but other envvars are carried over correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my Kubuntu or Debian there is a file `/etc/default/locale` like:

> ```
> #  File generated by update-locale
> LANG="pl_PL.UTF-8"
> ```

It is mentioned in various `/etc/pam.d/*` files. This is a fragment of `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

> ```
> # Read environment variables from /etc/environment and
> # /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
> session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
> # In Debian 4.0 (etch), locale-related environment variables were moved to
> # /etc/default/locale, so read that as well.
> session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
> ```

Now from [`man 5 pam.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.conf):

> When a PAM aware privilege granting application is started, it activates its attachment to the PAM-API. This activation performs a number of tasks, the most important being the reading of the configuration file(s): `/etc/pam.conf`. Alternatively, this may be the contents of the `/etc/pam.d/` directory. The presence of this directory will cause Linux-PAM to ignore `/etc/pam.conf`.

When a user logs in via SSH, `sshd` forks itself and this is the moment `/etc/pam.d/sshd` does its job. See [`man 8 pam_env`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_env), it is responsible for setting/unsetting environment variables. I wasn't sure if `sshd` forks before or after accepting variables from a client, so I made a simple test. I commented out this single line on my Debian server:

> ```
> session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
> ```

and the issue you pointed out was fixed (tested with `LANG=C ssh myserver` in my case). I uncommented the line and the issue reappeared.

Comment: This is where the variable setting came from on my system as well. Running `dpkg-reconfigure locales` allowed me to set the new default. Also interesting--the output of `locale -a`, `en_US.utf8`, doesn't match the name the variable is set to, `en_US.UTF-8`. What a strange world we have created for ourselves.